# Apple Watch crashes on bit operations with error code Thread1: exc_breakpoint(code=exc_arm_breakpoint,subcode=0xe7ffdefe)

Tags: swift, swift3, apple-watch, watchos-3

I am hashing user data on an Apple Watch using SHA1 and when running the `SHA1Bytes` function, I get the following error:

> Thread1: exc_breakpoint(code=exc_arm_breakpoint,subcode=0xe7ffdefe).
>   This specific line gives me the error:
>   `j = ( UInt32((msg[i]<<24) | (msg[i+1]<<16) | (msg[i+2]<<8) | msg[i+3]) )`

This is the piece of code from which the above line is extracted:

```
class func SHA1Bytes(msg: [Int])->String{
        func rotateLeft(number: UInt32, rotateBy: UInt32)->UInt32{
            return ((number << rotateBy) | (number>>(32-rotateBy)))
        }

        func cvt_hex(value: UInt32)->String{
            var str = ""
            for i:UInt32 in stride(from: 7, through: 0, by: -1){
                let v: UInt32 = (value >> (i*4)&0x0f)
                str += String(v,radix: 16, uppercase: false)
            }
            return str
        }

        var W = [UInt32](repeating: 0, count: 80)
        var H0 = UInt32("67452301",radix: 16)!
        var H1 = UInt32("EFCDAB89",radix: 16)!
        var H2 = UInt32("98BADCFE",radix: 16)!
        var H3 = UInt32("10325476",radix: 16)!
        var H4 = UInt32("C3D2E1F0",radix: 16)!

        var wordArray = [UInt32]()
        for k in stride(from: 0, to: msg.count-3, by: 4) {
            let j = ( UInt32((msg[k]<<24) | (msg[k+1]<<16) | (msg[k+2]<<8) | msg[k+3]) )
            wordArray.append(j)
        }
        ...
        return encoded.uppercased()
    }
```

The exact same code runs perfectly in an iOS Playground, but crashes when running on a first generation Apple Watch. I have checked and the input array exists, I am trying to access existing elements of it and the result of `j` should not overflow.
The code fails with the following variable values:

`j=(UInt32) 2308511418, k=(Int)48, msg=([Int])56values`

and these are the values of msg:

```
[47]    Int 217
[48]    Int 137
[49]    Int 153
[50]    Int 22
[51]    Int 186
[52]    Int 163
[53]    Int 41
[54]    Int 208
[55]    Int 104
```

Comment: 1. SHA1 is not encryption, it is a cryptographic hash function. 2. Use Common Crypto not a local implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, however I want to recreate the exact same approach as the backend does authentication, so it would be better to correct this piece of code. And I am still curious why this is not working on the Watch while it works perfectly in playground...

Comment: SHA1 is a standard method, unless there is an error in the code you can use different implementations and obtain the same results.

Comment: I understand it, but changing to a standard method still does help me understand what caused this error. Moreover, I want to keep my project pure Swift and avoid having to create a bridging header.

Comment: Ah, pure swift idealogy, damn correctness and performance. Swift3: `let messageData = string.data(using:.utf8)!` `var digestData = Data(count: Int(CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH))` `_ = digestData.withUnsafeMutableBytes {digestBytes in` `messageData.withUnsafeBytes {messageBytes in` `CC_SHA1(messageBytes, CC_LONG(messageData.count), digestBytes)` `}` `}`

Comment: You do need a bridging header for this to work, Swift gives unresolved identifier error for CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH, CC_SHA1 and CC_LONG, which is the expected result, since all of these are part of Common Crypto, which only exists in Obj-C.

Comment: Yes, a bridging header is needed and the addition of Security.framework to the project. On the other hand Common Crypto utilized hardware support and is guaranteed to be correct

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I managed to figure out that the simulator is not crashing even if a UInt32 overflows, however, the 32bit Apple Watch does crash in this case.
The solution was to use an overflow operator, which only exists for addition, subtraction and multiplication. Hence, I changed bitwise left shift to multiplication by 2^(number of bits to be shifted).
This is the correct solution: `UInt32(msg[k])&*UInt32(1<<24)`

`let j = (UInt32(msg[k])&*UInt32(1<<24))|UInt32(msg[k+1]&*(1<<16))|UInt32(msg[k+2]&*(1<<8))|UInt32(msg[k+3])`

Comment: It is best to really rely FIPS certified or well vetted implementations.

Comment: I understand your security concerns, but please understand that I did not choose not to use Common Crypto by accident, I had to take other considerations into account as well.

Answer (score 0):

The first generation Apple Watch is a 32-bit device and has different overflow limits compared to a 64-bit device.

On a 32-bit device, the `Int` type is 32-bit and you risk shifting into the sign bit.

Try the following in a playground:

```
UInt32(Int64(153) << 24) // Equivalent to your code

UInt32(Int32(153) << 24) // Simulates a 32-bit device and crashes.

UInt32(153) << 24         // A possible solution
```

Comment: You are right, for some reason the playground does not crash even if a UInt32 overflows.
However, even your third line causes an overflow, which the playground ignores, but Apple Watch does not, but I have found a solution and added it as an answer. I had to use overflow multiplication instead of bitwise left shift.